# iOS CBManagerState.unsupported in custom keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

When using CBCentralManagerDelegate in a custom keyboard extension centralManagerDidUpdateState always gives the unsupported state.

I have updated info.plist with:
`NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`
`NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`
and added `RequestsOpenAccess` attribute.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user must also manually give their consent to full access in the settings app:

General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Custom keyboard -> Allow Full Access